# Django import-export with FK constraint

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have been attempting to import data into my Django project using Django import-export.  I have two models Ap and Job, Job has a FK relationship with Ap. Using the Admin, I can select the file and the type, CSV.  So far my program seems to run, but gets hung up on the FK. I'm close, something is off and causing the import script to fail.

Models.py

```
class Ap(models.Model):
    line_num = models.IntegerField()
    vh = models.IntegerField()
    vz = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=statuses, default="select", max_length=40)
    classified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Job(models.Model):
    aplink = models.ForeignKey(Ap, related_name=(
        "job2ap"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_num = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(
        choices=categories, default="select", max_length=40)
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=statuses, default="select", max_length=40)
    dcma = models.BooleanField(default=False),
    due_date = models.DateField(blank=True),
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
class ImportView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = ImportForm()
        return render(request, 'importdata.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = ImportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        job_resource = JobResource()
        data_set = Dataset()
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['import_file']
            imported_data = data_set.load(file.read())
            result = job_resource.import_data(
                data_set, dry_run=True)  # Test the data import

            if not result.has_errors():
                job_resource.import_data(
                    data_set, dry_run=False)  # Actually import now

        else:
            form = ImportForm()
        return render(request, 'importdata.html', {'form': form})
```

resource.py

```
class CharRequiredWidget(widgets.CharWidget):
    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        val = super().clean(value)
        if val:
            return val
        else:
            raise ValueError('this field is required')


class ForeignkeyRequiredWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):
    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if value:
            print(self.field, value)
            return self.get_queryset(value, row, *args, **kwargs).get(**{self.field: value})
        else:
            raise ValueError(self.field + " required")


class JobResource(resources.ModelResource):
    aplink = fields.Field(column_name='aplink', attribute='aplink', widget=ForeignkeyRequiredWidget(Ap,'id'),
                        saves_null_values=False)
    job_num = fields.Field(saves_null_values=False, column_name='job_num', attribute='job_num',
                        widget=widgets.IntegerWidget())
    description = fields.Field(column_name='description', attribute='description', saves_null_values=False, 
                        widget=CharRequiredWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('aplink', 'job_num', 'description',)
        clean_model_instances=True
```

admin.py

```
class JobResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model=Job
        fields=('aplink','job_num','description',)
        
class JobAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = JobResource

admin.site.register(Job, JobAdmin)
```

CSV file, data to import.  I have tried leaving the first column empty, as will as putting the Id of the only Ap stored in the table ie 1.  I have also tried hard coding the line_num, which is 1200 the first column as well.

CSV file for importing data:

[image: CSV file for importing data]

Date importing errors:

[image: Date importing errors]

Comment: try adding 'id' to your list of fields

Answer (score 0):

In your resources, while defining fields, you need to include id field in the list. So change `JobResource` to the following:

```py
class JobResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('id', 'aplink', 'job_num', 'description')
```

If you have defined a custom id field, then you will need to provide:

```py
import_id_fields = ('your_id_field')
```